# WorkflowFoundation Validation Style not displayed in WFDesigner

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, workflow-foundation-4, validation, workflow-activity

In a WF4 rehosting Application I need to validate an Activity based on custom parameters, which are stored in a database.

When the user entered some values and the selection is changed in the designer the overwritten `CacheMetadata` Method is called as follows:

```
protected override void CacheMetadata(CodeActivityMetadata metadata)
{
  if (!ParamCache.ContainsKey(InstanceId.ToString())) return;

  var paramsToValidate = ParamCache.Get(InstanceId.ToString());

  var validationErrors = (from paramToValidate in paramsToValidate
      let errorMessage = paramToValidate.Validate()
      where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage)
      select new ValidationError(errorMessage, false)).ToList();

 foreach (var validationError in validationErrors)
 {
   metadata.AddValidationError(validationError);
 }
}
```

During runtime the error collection is evaluated using this Validate Method:

```
public void Validate()
{
   var activity = ModelItem.GetCurrentValue() as Activity;
   if (activity != null)
   {
       var validationResults = ActivityValidationServices.Validate(activity);

       var designerRegionVieWModel = Parent as DesignerRegionViewModel;
       IsValid = validationResults.Errors.Count <= 0;

       ...       
}
```

Although `ValidationError` objects have been added, and `IsValid` is false the designer is not updated to visualize the errors with the red exclamation mark style.

However, if I add some Errors (for testing purpose) right on the beginning of the `CacheMetadata` Method the errors are displayed as required.

Could this be some timing problem or is there some additional runtime evaluation which has to be triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how it works. The entire Workflow needs to be Re-Evaluated. You can achieve this by using the WorkflowDesigner's `ValidationService`.

```
var validationService = workflowDesigner.Context.Services.GetService<ValidationService>();
validationService.ValidateWorkflow();
```